# Solving for one variable in a summation

Tags: python, math, scipy, sympy

Hi so I'm trying to use sympy to solve for one variable (x) in the following equation:

[image]

where  s_calc is:

[image]

So mkt is given as 3.60 SPs are as follows.

Here is what the manual calculation by guessing looks like in Excel where x was approximated to be 3.84 (this is what I am trying to determine):

[image]

The s_calc of 8.5 => 3.84/((8.5-1)+3.84) = 0.34

```
s_calc = (x/((SP-1)+x))


from sympy import *

SPs = [8.5,10,4.6,8,7,19,13,5,5.5,21,31,61]
mkt = 3.6

x = Symbol('x', real=True)


eqn = Eq((sum([(x/((SP-1)+x)) for SP in SPs])),mkt)

print solve(eqn)
```

The result is:

```
[-56.0760097663833,
 -28.2321104629407,
 -19.2596055912120,
 -16.2599057021677,
 -11.1953370291770,
 -8.53265746170317,
 -7.27171869196792,
 -6.44292213715154,
 -5.20607622713613,
 -4.24324047973505,
 -3.74708311709209,
 0.0]
```

Not only does it give me a list of values which does not resemble anything like 3.84 which was what I calculated x to be. In addition solve is computationally quite heavy and takes a good 15 seconds to yield those results.

I was hoping someone might be able to guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function *solve( )* in SymPy is currently being rewritten as *solveset( )*, in the future, *solve* could be deprecated.

Anyway, using *solveset( )*:

```
In [13]: solveset(eqn, x)
Out[13]: 
{-54.9173331680142, -27.8044066980778, -19.1811507147424, -15.7703025652324,
-11.0087893729661, -8.45970674653321, -7.25698321320126, -6.38855281836353,
-5.07892647766187, -4.21937087225829, -3.73292307178124, 3.83749333787992}
```

The value 3.83749333787992 is among the solutions (it looks a bit like your 3.84).

Otherwise, as your equation has only one symbolic variable and the rest being numerical, you could try to lambdify your expression and use tools from `scipy`:

```
In [25]: eqfunc = lambdify(x, eqn.lhs - eqn.rhs)

In [26]: import scipy.optimize

In [28]: scipy.optimize.broyden1(eqfunc, [3.84])
Out[28]: array([ 3.83749334])
```